# How to use dynamic className with TypeAnimation component?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, dynamic-class

I am using a package called

> react-type-animation

for a typewriter text effect with react and tailwind css. But when I add dynamic class to the TypeAnimation component, it does not work. Here is the code that I have tried:

```
<TypeAnimation sequence={[
              "TEXT1",
              2000,
              "TEXT2",
              2000,
              "TEXT3",
              2000,
            ]}
              speed={50}
              className={`text-${theme}-500`}
              wrapper="span"
              repeat={Infinity}
            />
```

But when i use static class like text-red-500, it works fine. Is there any way to use dynamic class to the TypeAnimation component?

Answer (score 0):

As per [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names):

> The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as *complete unbroken strings* in your source files.
>
> If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS:
>
> **Don’t construct class names dynamically**
>
> ```js
> <div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>
> ```
>
> In the example above, the strings `text-red-600` and `text-green-600` do not exist, so Tailwind will not generate those classes.
> Instead, make sure any class names you’re using exist in full:
>
> **Always use complete class names**
>
> ```js
> <div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>
> ```

You could:

- Have the entire class in the variable you pass to `className` like

  ```js
  const textColor = '';
  if (theme == 'red') {
    textColor = 'text-red-500';
  }

  // …

  <TypeAnimation … className={textColor} />
  ```
- Use the `style` attribute for truly dynamic colors, if `theme` can be converted to a valid CSS color value (or you could [get the color from Tailwind](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#referencing-in-java-script)):

  ```js
  <TypeAnimation … style={{ color: theme }} />;
  ```
- [`safelist` the classes](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes), if you have a limited number of known colors:

  ```js
  module.exports = {
    safelist: [
      'text-red-500',
      // …
    ],
    // …
  ];
  ```

Comment: Thanks. I added the classes to the safelist and now they are working fine.

Comment: I can see the docs does not recommendes to use safelist. So I went with the if else method. I generated a whole class name and then added the className to the TypeAnimation component.